# Wso2 esb JMS consume and produce message with ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, wso2, wso2-esb

Hi am working with WSO2 ESB 4.7.0

I have created a proxy which listens to a jms queue and consumes a message from that queue and place that  in the other jms queue,below is the code of my proxy.

```
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="DLQ.kumar"
       transports="jms"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
                  <address uri="jms:/kumar?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;  java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616"/>
               </endpoint>
         </send>
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

As per the process it should read the message from DLQ.kumar and place that message to kumar,But it is reading the messages from DLQ.kumar and failing to place it in the kumar.

My ESB is reflecting the flowing error

```
    JMSUtils Cannot locate destination : Kumar
    [2015-08-04 13:09:51,265] ERROR - JMSOutTransportInfo Couldn't locate the JMS destination Kumar of type generic extracted from the URL jms:/Kumar?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&                 java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616
    javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [dynamicQueues/Kumar] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [dynamicQueues].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContext.lookup(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:1030)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.lookup(JMSUtils.java:583)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.lookupDestination(JMSUtils.java:814)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.getDestination(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:184)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.loadConnectionFactoryFromProperties(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:132)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.createJMSSender(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:330)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:125)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
    [2015-08-04 13:09:51,266]  INFO - AxisEngine [MessageContext: logID=93b40feadaf9ce3b4ef4eb0952395ebbfd2b79b95d9bd0fa] Couldn't locate the JMS destination Kumar of type generic extracted from the URL jms:/Kumar?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&                 java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616
     INFO - AxisEngine [MessageContext: logID=93b40feadaf9ce3b4ef4eb0952395ebbfd2b79b95d9bd0fa] Couldn't locate the JMS destination Kumar of type generic extracted from the URL jms:/Kumar?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&                 java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616
[2015-08-04 13:09:51,266] ERROR - AsyncCallback Couldn't locate the JMS destination Kumar of type generic extracted from the URL jms:/Kumar?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&                 java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616
org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.AxisJMSException: Couldn't locate the JMS destination Kumar of type generic extracted from the URL jms:/Kumar?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&                 java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.handleException(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:250)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.getDestination(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.loadConnectionFactoryFromProperties(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:132)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.createJMSSender(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:330)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [dynamicQueues/Kumar] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [dynamicQueues].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContext.lookup(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:1030)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.lookup(JMSUtils.java:583)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.lookupDestination(JMSUtils.java:814)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.getDestination(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:184)
    ... 8 more
[2015-08-04 13:09:51,267]  WARN - AsyncCallback Executing fault handler due to exception encountered
[2015-08-04 13:09:51,267]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : endpoint_b1b40feadaf9ce3b4767fa0952395ebba03b79b95d9bd0fa will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<endpoint>
     <address uri="jms:/dynamicQueues/kumar?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=KumarQueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue/>
</endpoint>
```

Or you define your connection factory into axis2.xml and use this uri : `jms:/dynamicQueues/kumar?transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=myQueueConnectionFactory`

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured JMS Transport Sender by uncommenting following configuration in $ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file? If not, please configure it and restart the ESB.

```xml
<transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender"/>
```

Comment: Yes i have done all the modifications required to work with Jms Queues.